# Webfont Kit showing wrong font....!

Tags: css, fonts

I was attempting to install
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lemonchicken
Which should look like [image] taken from my maintenance page which it worked fine on.

But on my actual website it looks like this [image]

My CSS is

```
/* Add font */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lemonchickenregular';
    src: url('../font/LEMONCHI-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/LEMONCHI-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/LEMONCHI-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/LEMONCHI-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/LEMONCHI-webfont.svg#lemonchickenregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
/* Hide copyright */
.site-info {
    display:none;
}
/* Make main content area white */
.content-area {
    background-color:white;
}
/* Change all font on the website */
* {
    font-family: 'lemonchickenregular';
}
```

I'm not sure why it shows this other font. Which is different than the default fault on my website but not my installed font.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a fiddle showing the problem. Looks like the font simply isn't loading correctly. Also, * is an ineffective css selector. It is better to apply a global font using body { font-family: 'yourfont' }

Comment: You don't need a giant font stack [in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff), remove all fonts except the WOFF format, and then see if you can still reproduce the problem. I know, fontsquirrel for some insane reason still *gives* you all those other formats, but EOT and SVG are legacy and [abandoned](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font) respectively, and ttf and otf are universal fonts, which makes browsers behave much stricter about whether they have permission to be used. Simplify  your code so that it's easier to find problems: remove all but the WOFF resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*never* set a CSS rule to apply to `*`, it loses all conflict resolutions with other rules that might apply at the same time, because *any* other rule is going to be more specific, including browser specified base style rules, and they will get applied instead. In CSS, any selector that is "more specific" gets to override any selector that is "less specific", which is why `p.someclass` overrides `p`, and why literally *anything* that isn't `*` gets to override what you say in `*`.

If you want a cascading rule for all your content, set the rule on an actual element; specify the font-family for the top-most element in your content, and then override it with more specific rules for elements that need it.

```
body {
  font-family: lemonchicken;
}
```

Comment: you're also still using a million font formats instead of just WOFF. However, I'm going to tell you to open your browser dev tools, and look at the console. Next time you ask a question like this, where you have a website, include its url in your post so people can see what you're talking about instead of having to guess. With the console open, It's *pretty obvious* why you're not seeing the font getting applied.

Comment: I have been attempting to debug in browser dev tools. And have seen no obvious reason. Removing everything except WOFF did nothing to resolve the issue. Neither did using body instead of * . Furthermore I don't have a million font formats I have 5 for this font. That should be no reason for the font to work. Only make it more compatible with older browsers. Which people still use!

Comment: You had five, two of which *don't exist anymore*, and two of which are system font formats, not webfont formats. As of January 12th, Microsoft finally abandoned IE9 and below, so: no, no one on even a remotely recent OS still uses them, but if they are: they are on no longer supported Microsoft software. You don't support IE5 anymore, either, and IE9 and below are now in the same category as IE5: EOL abandoned. Anyway, I see you fixed your problem (because the dev tools no longer say the browser is not allowed to download the font), so it looks like it's time to deleted this question.

Comment: I did not fix it. That is the maintenance page where it has all formats and works perfectly. On the live site I still can't get it to work.

Comment: And is the live site *also* saying "not allowed to download `<fonturl>`"? Because that's obviously a thing you want to sort out (depending on your server software, you might need to whitelist the fonts dir before clients can download files from it)

Comment: Turns out I had to add /wp-content/themes/chaipunzelsbowtique-theme/fonts/ I'm wondering if there is a shorter or more secure way to call that whole path?

Comment: presumably someone wrote a webfont plugin that makes all of that much easier.